# How to reserve a tcp local port?

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, bind

In my application, I bind a socket to the port 38614.

While in test, I find sometime the port is used by another application.

So I failed to bind on it and get the error, "Address already in use".

I did some research, and find I could set the parameter /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_loca_port_range to reserve the port for my application.

So I add a new line "net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 50000 60000" to the file /etc/sysctl.conf.

Then I reboot the system.

But I still find a port 34660 out of the range which I set is used by some application.

```
[root@xxxx ~]# netstat -apn | grep fe80::cef1:3
tcp6       0      0 fe80::cef1:12345 fe80::cef1:34660 ESTABLISHED 2401/xxxx
```

So what should I do to reserve some ports for my application?

Could anyone give me some advice?

Another method is using a small port, such as 1001 which is not used by any other application, but I do not think it is a good idea for the ports smaller than 1024 are reserved for [well-known ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers).

===============================================================

I have found the answer of the question "[how do I reserve ports for my application?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15511/how-do-i-reserve-ports-for-my-application)"

While I don't think it is a good idea, for it is difficult to make sure that our application runs earlier than any other application. Actually my application has to start after another application which does some prepare for my application.

The linux system may assign any port in the port pool to any application when it need a port.

===============================================================

The  parameter "ip_local_reserved_ports" is similar to "ip_local_port_range", they are in the same folder, and it is much more difficult to be tested. In my test the parameter "ip_local_port_range" doesn't work as our expect, so I don't believe the "ip_local_reserved_ports" is ok.

B.R.
Forward

Comment: Why not use a different port?

Comment: Yes, I can, but the port may be used by another application. for excample I use 34660, you can see it also is used. If I want to keep my port is not used by any other application, I have to reserve it from system

Answer (score 0):

The idea to reserve the port is to block the usage of this port for an outgoing connection. I mean if you have a potential service that will open for LISTEN the port 8080, if you don't reserve it, and the range of ports include this port, could conflict with a outgoing connection that randomly uses 8080 as "source port".

Answer (score -2):

I'm quoting answers of [how do I reserve ports for my application?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15511/how-do-i-reserve-ports-for-my-application)

You could try with:

> sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_local_reserved_ports = 49000, 49001
>   drop it in /etc/sysctl.conf, and then run sysctl -p.
>
> To ensure the kernel won't give out 49000 and 49001 to clients as you wish to use them for your servers on linux.
>
> Note that this is untested.

However, this is the accepted answer to the question:

> Technically, there's no such thing as a "reserved port".
>
> In TCP/UDP, the only way to "reserve" a port is to actually bind() a socket to it. A bound port will not be used by other applications; an unused port is, well, unused so other applications are free to use it.
>
> If you are writing server software, then you can bind your sockets to specific ports as early as you want in the application code. Make the port numbers configurable, or at least clearly state them in the documentation, so that a systems administrator can quickly identify clashes and move conflicting applications to separate servers.

Comment: thanks for your idea.the parameter ip_local_reserved_port is similar to ip_local_port_range, they are in the same folder, the ip_local_port_range does't work as our expect, some ports out of range are used. so I don't believe the parameter ip_loca_reserved_ports work and it is more difficult to prove it ok.

Comment: For the answers of "how do I reserve ports for my application?", from my point of view, it is not  a good idea. I can't make sure my application run firstly in the system,  Actually my application runs secondly and the linux system assign the port to the first application.